# Skip the first row reading an EXCEL file by using creek in Ruby

Tags: ruby, excel

I have the following code. It works well except that I cannot get rid of the first row of an EXCEL file. I use Ruby and module creek.

```
workbook = Creek::Book.new 'file.xlsx'
    worksheets = workbook.sheets

    worksheets.each do |worksheet|
      worksheet.rows.each 2 do |row|
      treatment = row.values[0].to_i
      replicate = row.values[1].to_i
      station = row.values[2].to_i
      sample_depth = row.values[3].to_i
      sample_date = row.values[4].to_s
      top_depth = []
    end
  end
end
```

I have `worksheet.rows.each 2 do |row|` here but it does not work at all. I am curious about the right way of doing it. Thank you.

Comment: maybe hide the row and unhide it after processing? sorry, I haven't used ruby to access excel before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your inputs.

```
worksheet.rows.drop(1).each do |row|
```

actually does the work.

```
worksheets.drop(1).each do |worksheet|
```

performs on worksheet level. but this line inspired me! :)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
worksheet.rows.each_with_index do |row, index|
  if not index == 0
    treatment = row.values[0].to_i
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-each) doesn't take an index offset argument. Try using [`Enumerable#drop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop):

```
worksheets.drop(1).each do |worksheet|
  ...
end
```